# Shapes not aligned in Python:

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, valueerror

I'm new on stackoverflow and I'm trying to create a custom ridge regression model for a time series analysis. My goal is to predict the sign of stock return while using linear regression with ridge regularization. Details are below in the code. To perform my regression, I'm splitting my data into 5 equal blocks as training and test sets. In the for loop, I'm trying to cross validate my hyper parameters alpha and lambda to find best model in my ridge regression family. (As I'm new to Python, I couldn't make this in other simpler way. If you can correct my code in a simpler way, it would be better)

```
df =      [[5.029188 ,0.560895,-2.432905,-0.766467,4.97],
          [5.046780,-0.539126,-2.481951,-0.657977,4.990], 
          [5.270471,-0.398845,-2.622589,-1.455087,5.001],
          [5.450671,-0.336845,-2.352584,-1.235557,4.976],
          [5.247153,-0.653155,-2.246789,-1.164277,4.989],
          [5.797471,-0.498845,-2.432589,-1.555087,5.03],
          [5.350471,-0.598845,-2.672589,-1.655087,5.09],
          [5.320471,-0.698845,-2.234589,-1.755087,5.15],
          [5.650471,-0.798845,-2.765389,-1.355087,5.10],
          [5.760471,-0.898845,-2.223589,-1.255087,5.05],
          [5.225712,-0.198845,-2.876589,-1.155087,5.07],
          [5.650471,-0.298845,-2.345427,-1.455087,5.13],
          [5.122471,-0.356845,-2.586429,-1.567087,5.11],
          [5.890471,-0.543845,-2.454369,-1.123087,5.07],
          [5.240471,-0.235845,-2.543579,-1.789087,5.12],
          [5.980471,-0.654845,-2.245435,-1.245087,5.14],
          [5.120471,-0.876845,-2.466753,-1.323487,5.18],
          [5.650471,-0.234845,-2.235675,-1.355087,5.20],
          [5.432171,-0.765845,-2.353246,-1.765087,5.24],
          [5.765471,-0.458845,-2.356535,-1.245087,5.22],
          [5.029188 ,0.560895,-2.432905,-0.766467,5.21],
          [5.046780,-0.539126,-2.481951,-0.657977,5.32], 
          [5.270471,-0.398845,-2.622589,-1.455087,5.36],
          [5.450671,-0.336845,-2.352584,-1.235557,5.40],
          [5.247153,-0.653155,-2.246789,-1.164277,5.32],
          [5.797471,-0.498845,-2.432589,-1.555087,5.33],
          [5.350471,-0.598845,-2.672589,-1.655087,5.21],
          [5.320471,-0.698845,-2.234589,-1.755087,5.24],
          [5.650471,-0.798845,-2.765389,-1.355087,5.30],
          [5.760471,-0.898845,-2.223589,-1.255087,5.33],
          [5.225712,-0.198845,-2.876589,-1.155087,5.40],
          [5.650471,-0.298845,-2.345427,-1.455087,5.42],
          [5.122471,-0.356845,-2.586429,-1.567087,5.45],
          [5.890471,-0.543845,-2.454369,-1.123087,5.50],
          [5.240471,-0.235845,-2.543579,-1.789087,5.48],
          [5.980471,-0.654845,-2.245435,-1.245087,5.56],
          [5.120471,-0.876845,-2.466753,-1.323487,5.60],
          [5.650471,-0.234845,-2.235675,-1.355087,5.63],
          [5.432171,-0.765845,-2.353246,-1.765087,5.57],
          [5.765471,-0.458845,-2.356535,-1.245087,5.63]] 


  
# creating df object with columns specified    
data_new = pd.DataFrame(df, columns =['PC1', 'PC2','PC3','PC4','Price']) 

PC=['PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4']
```

```
   def ridge_regression(X, y, W, alpha=1, lambda_value=10, epochs=50):
    cost_hist=[]
    #W=initial weigths
    m = np.shape(X)[0]  # total number of samples
    n = np.shape(X)[1]  # total number of features
    
    X = np.concatenate((np.ones((m, 1)), X), axis=1)
 
    # iterate until the maximum number of epochs
    for current_iteration in np.arange(epochs):  # begin the process
 
        # compute the dot product between our feature 'X' and weight 'W'
        y_estimated = X.dot(W)
        
        y_estimated=pd.DataFrame(y_estimated)
        y=pd.DataFrame(y)
 
        # calculate the difference between the actual and predicted value
        sign_pred=np.sign(np.log(y_estimated)/np.log(y_estimated).shift(1)).fillna(0)
        sign_true=np.sign(np.log(y)/np.log(y).shift(1)).fillna(0)
        error = (sign_pred-sign_true)/m
        error=error.fillna(0)
        
        # regularization term
        ridge_reg_term = (lambda_value / 2 * m) * np.sum(np.square(W))
 
        # calculate the error + regularization term
        cost = (1 / 2 * m) * np.sum(error ** 2) + ridge_reg_term
 
        transpose=X.T
        dot_prod=pd.DataFrame(transpose.dot(error))
        gradient = (1 / m) * (dot_prod.iloc[:,0] + (lambda_value * W))
 
        # Now we have to update our weights
        W = W - alpha * gradient
        
        cost_hist.append(cost)
        
    weights=W
    
    return weights
```

```
    def BlockingTimeSeriesSplit(X,n_splits=5):
    train=[]
    test=[]
    for i in range(n_splits):
        n_samples = X.shape[0]
        k_fold_size = int(n_samples / n_splits)
        indices = np.arange(n_samples)
        start =i * k_fold_size
        stop = start + k_fold_size
        mid = int(0.5 * (stop - start)) + start
        train.append(indices[start: mid])
        test.append(indices[mid: stop])
    return train, test
```

```
n=5
f1_score=[]
alpha=[0.01,0.1,1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100,1000]
lambda_values=[1,2,3,5,10,20,30,50,100,200,300,500,1000]

a,b=BlockingTimeSeriesSplit(data_new,n)

for i in range(n):
    cv_train, cv_test = data_new.iloc[a[i]], data_new.iloc[b[i]]
    
    cv_validation,cv_test_new=train_test_split(cv_test,test_size=0.6)
    
    m_train=np.shape(cv_train[PC])[0]
    
    np.random.seed(11)
    W = np.random.randn(np.shape(cv_train[PC])[1] + 1, )
    
    weights_train=ridge_regression(cv_train[PC],cv_train['Price'],W)
    
    weights_train=pd.DataFrame(weights_train)
    
    
    for a in alpha:
        for l in lambda_values:
    
            weights_validation=ridge_regression(cv_validation[PC],cv_validation['Price'],weights_train,alpha=a,lambda_value=l)
    
            weights_validation=pd.DataFrame(weights_validation)
        
            m_valid=np.shape(cv_valid[PC])[0]
            X = np.concatenate((np.ones((m_valid, 1)), cv_train[PC]), axis=1)
    
            y_pred=pd.DataFrame(X.dot(weights_validation))
    
    
            # calculate the difference between the actual and predicted value
            sign_pred=np.sign(np.log(y_pred)/np.log(y_pred).shift(1)).fillna(0)
            sign_true=np.sign(np.log(cv_test['Price'])/np.log(cv_test['Price']).shift(1)).fillna(0)
    
            tn, fp, fn, tp =confusion_matrix(sign_true,sign_pred,labels=[0,1]).ravel()
            precision=tp/(tp+fp)
            recall=tp/(tp+fn)
            f1=2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall)
            f1_score.append(f1)

    
            print("F1 Score: {}".format(np.mean(f1_score)))
        
return weights_validation
```

I'm receiving this error which is about the shape of the two dataframes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-439-08f7c7adf57f> in <module>
     25         for l in lambda_values:
     26 
---> 27             weights_validation=ridge_regression(cv_validation[PC],cv_validation['Price'],weights_train,alpha=a,lambda_value=l)
     28 
     29             weights_validation=pd.DataFrame(weights_validation)

<ipython-input-430-c693a48acc42> in ridge_regression(X, y, W, alpha, lambda_value, epochs)
     40 
     41         transpose=X.T
---> 42         dot_prod=pd.DataFrame(transpose.dot(error))
     43         gradient = (1 / m) * (dot_prod.iloc[:,0] + (lambda_value * W))
     44 
ValueError: shapes (11,23) and (46,2) not aligned: 23 (dim 1) != 46 (dim 0)
```

I'm struggling to understand how my error shape become (46,2) as when I trace back it, I see that it should be (23,1) and the dot production should be performed. I'm stuck at this point and looking forward to hearing your thoughts on that.

Comment: As a casual observation, 46 is 2 * 23. Are you accidentally doubling up your array(s) somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I suspect it but I could not find where it gets doubled up exactly.

Comment: Remember to read through the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't yet: can you turn this code into a [mcve] that folks can drop in a file and run? (e.g. with hardcoded short inputs etc)

Comment: I've just added the link for downloading the dataset to reproduce the error.

Comment: I really recommend you try to make a minimal reproducible example. Not only are you more likely to get a good answer, you will probably find the error before even posting here.

Comment: That's part of why I asked you to, as well: the [mcve] exercise is not for us, that's just a bonus. It's one of those debugging tools that 99% of the time lets you find errors because you're sitting down trying to make the code as small as possible to show to others. Going "here's the link to the data" makes your brain go "and now I'm done", whereas trying to actively form an MCVE makes your brain go "okay, so what do I NEED to show this off." and home in on the absolute smallest possible set of inputs and code, almost always forcing yourself to run into "oh, wait, what? why is this [...]"

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using scikit-learn to do this in 3 lines of code?

Comment: I do not know how to reduce this into 3 lines of code but my error is not continous i'm converting my stock price predictions into the the sign of stock return and updating my weights to minimize the error which is the difference between predicted sign and actual sign. This is why I wrote a custom function. For cross-validation, there could be another simpler way if you're talking about it, however I couldn't do it correctly. I'm open to any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The last code:

```
transpose=X.T
transpose.dot(error)
```

from the error: `(11,23) and (46,2)`

So some how `error` is (46,2), while `X` is (23,10).

The challenge is to trace these arguments back to your inputs to the function

```
cv_validation[PC], cv_validation['Price'], weights_train
```

OK, `X` is `cv_validation[PC]`

Oops, I see that you did post `ridge_regression`.  I haven't looked at that.

```
error = (sign_pred-sign_true)/m
```

Tracing dimensions thru those two inputs is more than I can readily do.  Why are you using a dataframe here?  Just to get the `shift`?  I don't know if that complicates things.

You say `error` should be  `(23,1)`, but the error says it's `(46,2)`.  We can't verify that.  You may need to add some diagnostic shape prints.

Comment: Hello hpaulj, I'm using dataframe to be able to get difference between two consecutive periods with shift(). Is there any way to do it differently? I just added a minimal reproducible example with a reduced number.